# How to implement Alphabetical section headers in a UITableView having content getting from DataBase

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, uitableview

Till now I have implemented `UITableView` by populate the contents from the database

By retrieving in an **array from sqlite data base**

`storedContactsArray = [Sqlitefile selectAllContactsFromDB];`

so no multiple sections , section headers and returns `storedContactsArray.count` as number of rows.

Now i need to populate the same data in table view but **The data set in Alpabetical sections in alphabetical order.**

I tried with

```
alphabetsArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E",@"F",@"G",@"H",@"I",@"J",@"K",@"L",@"M",@"N",@"O",@"P",@"Q",@"R",@"S",@"T",@"U",@"V",@"W",@"X",@"Y",@"Z",nil];


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return [alphabetsArray count];
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
      return alphabetsArray;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
      return [alphabetsArray objectAtIndex:section];
}
```

**[image: in need as follows]**

But in case of `numberOfRowsInSectio`n it fails since there is no contacts in `storedContactsArray` initially

Error occurs:  `-[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 25 beyond bounds for empty array`

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return [[storedContactsArray objectAtIndex:section] count]
}
```

any advice of use full links pls

Comment: Were you able to get this to work? I'm doing something similar, even with the below advice, but my data is not showing in alphabetical order. It's getting grouped properly, but not in alpha order.

Answer (score 17):

To achieve your requirement you need to first separate out all the data in to section as Alphabetical order. which is as following.

Here section is a Mutable Dictionary in which we will get all data as alphabetical sets.

```
 //Inside ViewDidLoad Method

 sections = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; ///Global Object

 BOOL found;

for (NSString *temp in arrayYourData)
{        
    NSString *c = [temp substringToIndex:1];

    found = NO;

    for (NSString *str in [sections allKeys])
    {
        if ([str isEqualToString:c])
        {
            found = YES;
        }
    }

    if (!found)
    {     
        [sections setValue:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:c];
    }
}
for (NSString *temp in arrayYourData)
{
    [[sections objectForKey:[temp substringToIndex:1]] addObject:temp];
}



-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[sections allKeys]count];
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[sections valueForKey:[[[sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:section]] count];
}


-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      static NSString* CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
      UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     if(cell == Nil)
     {
           cell  = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     }
     NSString *titleText = [[sections valueForKey:[[[sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     cell.textLabel.text = titleText;
     return cell;
 }
```

Please try it I am using it and it working fine
Hope it helps you !!!

Comment: thank you it works fine for visable, but the other content except our array does not seems in order. Evey time details textlabel shows the contet in fist section in every section

 'Contact *contact = [storedContactsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       cell.detailTextLabel.text = contact.companyName';

Comment: i edited my question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13172527/problm-while-creating-the-alphabetical-section-headers-un-uitableview-problm-wi