# Creating the alphabetical section headers in uitableview. Issue with other fields detail textlabel, imageview and didselect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, uitableview

In my table view i need to display Contact name, Company name and Picture of contact person.

[image]

I can add/edit a contact from the **Add/Edit Contact** page.

[image]

When I entered values in add/edit page I store them in a dictionay.

I retrieved ContactNames in an array ContactsArray and using this array I tried to set sections and headers.

in this process other fields are not displayed what we have saved, **observe detail Text label** even this problem in didSelectRow method also..

When I selected 1st row of any section it navigates to the details page for 1sr row of 1st section

When I selected 2nd row of any section it navigates to the details page for 2nd row of 1st section

it may be the problem of sections

//Inside ViewDidLoad Method

```
  sections = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; ///Global Object

  BOOL found;

  for (NSString *temp in contactsArray)
  {        
        NSString *c = [temp substringToIndex:1];

        found = NO;

        for (NSString *str in [sections allKeys])
        {
              if ([str isEqualToString:c])
              {
                    found = YES;
              }
        }

        if (!found)
        {     
              [sections setValue:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:c];
        }
  }
  for (NSString *temp in contactsArray)
  {
        [[sections objectForKey:[temp substringToIndex:1]] addObject:temp];
  }

      [contactsTable reloadData];
```

}

Tableview methods

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
      return [[sections allKeys]count];
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
      return [[sections valueForKey:[[[sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:section]] count];
}


-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      static NSString* CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
      UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
      if(cell == Nil)
      {
            cell  = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
      }
      NSString *titleText = [[sections valueForKey:[[[sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

       cell.textLabel.text = titleText;

      Contact *contact = [storedContactsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      Contact *contactPicture = [storedPicsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


          _____________________________________

           cell.detailTextLabel.text = contact.companyName;
          UIImage *contactImage =  [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:contactPicture.contactImage];
           cell.imageView.image = contactImage;
            _______________________________
              return cell;
}
```

Even when I sect **Bb** it navigates to hte **AAAAA** page details..

I tried with this link  http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43374/0/page/2 alsoo even I repeats the same issue

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      EditContact *editContact = [[EditContact alloc] init];
      if([self.storedContactsArray count] != 0)
      {
            Contact *contactsDict = [storedContactsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            editContact.contactInfo = contactsDict;

            Contact *picsDict = [storedPicsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            editContact.storedPicsDict = picsDict;
      }

      [self.navigationController pushViewController:editContact animated:YES];
      [editContact release];
      [storedContactsArray release];

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can we know what you are doing in tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: delegate method?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the row index over multiple sections. In every section `indexPath.row` will start at 0 again. You have tu use also `indexPath.section`.

In my opinion, you have two ways to solve this:

1. Refactor your whole code to get an dictionary with all starting characters **and** an array containg all contacts inside
2. Save the whole contact in an sub array of your `sections` dictionary for **every** character (a, b, and so on). If you have done this, you can use `sections` instead of `storedContactsArray` and `storedPicsArray`, e.g. like this: `NSDictionary *contactData = [[[sections objectForKey:[[sections allKeys] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectForKey:@"contacts"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

Also, you can save various lines of code:

```
  for (NSString *temp in contactsArray)
  {        
        NSString *c = [temp substringToIndex:1];

        if ([sections objectForKey:c] == nil)
        {     
              [sections setValue:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:c];
        }
  }
```

Is the same as:

```
  for (NSString *temp in contactsArray)
  {        
        NSString *c = [temp substringToIndex:1];

        found = NO;

        for (NSString *str in [sections allKeys])
        {
              if ([str isEqualToString:c])
              {
                    found = YES;
              }
        }

        if (!found)
        {     
              [sections setValue:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:c];
        }
  }
```

Comment: i have some confuse about your pint 2... Save the whole contact in an sub array of your sections dictionary for every character (a, b, and so on). If you have done this, you can use sections instead of storedContactsArray and

Comment: You need a structured dictionary with 2 dimensions. The first is the section, and the second is the contact data. This allows you to access  the data by section **and** row.

Comment: yes i have sections dictionary in this format only
{
    A =     (
        Aaaaa
Aaaaa2
    );
    B =     (
        Bb
    );
    c =     (
        cccc
    );
}